# Android Dev: why can't i check vail in EditText

Tags: android-studio, android-edittext

I have code in android studio and it have some error in if structure.

```
EditText etPrice = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPrice);
int price = Integer.parseInt(etPrice.getText().toString());

if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(etPrice.getText())){
    gia=price;
}
else{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"enter price lz",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Does anyone have an idea how to fix it?

Comment: What kind fo error do you get? Could you post the errormessage and the stacktrace?

Comment: error is: FATAL EXCEPTION: main                                                                            java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
 //if i don't use if structure, just use gia=price and it work